# Question Sort Method Scroller Too Small and Close to Menu

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I'm using Stack Exchange iOS App
Version 1.3.1.214 on an iPad.

The question sort method scroller is too close to the side menu button.

When trying to change the sort/filter method, I often end up opening the side menu.

[image: screenshot]